# Saving Outlook attachment with date in the filename

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

All I want to do is very simply set a date variable in VBA in the following code.  However if I try to use mydate = date, it doesn't work:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
Dim mydate As String

mydate = date

saveFolder = "T:\EC Portfolio Reports\CCA Credit Europe\ctpty"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & mydate & objAtt.FileName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

to have the date as a string, use `format`. This will also allow you to remove any illegal characters in the date, as `date` will return slashes - Filenames cannot contain **/:*?"<>|**

use `mydate = format(date,"yyyymmdd")`